# Selecting columns in R data frame based on those *not* in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm familiar with being able to extract columns from an R data frame (or matrix) like so:

```
df.2 <- df[, c("name1", "name2", "name3")]
```

But can one use a `!` or other tool to select *all but those listed columns*?

For background, I have a data frame with quite a few column vectors and I'd like to avoid:

- Typing out the majority of the names when I could just remove a minority
- Using the much shorter `df.2 <- df[, c(1,3,5)]` because when my .csv file changes, my code goes to heck since the numbering isn't the same anymore. I'm new to R and think I've learned the hard way not to use number vectors for larger df's that might change.

I tried:

```
df.2 <- df[, !c("name1", "name2", "name3")]
df.2 <- df[, !=c("name1", "name2", "name3")]
```

And just as I was typing this, found out that this works:

```
df.2 <- df[, !names(df) %in% c("name1", "name2", "name3")]
```

Is there a better way than this last one?

Comment: I generally shorten your last example using a custom infix operator: `'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')`.

Comment: @joran Doesn't that only shorten it by a `!`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, though most people use () so they'd be saving another 2. Its more about readability for me.

Comment: The last one does not seem to work with data.table's fread.

Comment: The last one does not work with data.table's fread. For data.table, I got it working with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094645/select-subset-of-columns-in-data-table-r) (with=FALSE). *I wish there was some package-independent solution.*

Comment: Use `-c ` instead of `c` .  `df.2 <- subset(df, select = -c(name1,name2, name3))`

Answer (score 39):

An alternative to `grep` is `which`:

```
df.2 <- df[, -which(names(df) %in% c("name1", "name2", "name3"))]
```

Comment: The technique here is otherwise the same as in Data.table but one comma more such that `myData[,,!removeCols]`.

Answer (score 14):

You can make a shorter call that is also more generalizable with negative-grep:

```
df.2 <- df[, -grep("^name[1:3]$", names(df) )]
```

Since grep returns numerics you can use the negative vector indexing to remove columns. You could add further number or more complex patterns.

Answer (score 12):

`dplyr::select()` has several options for dropping specific columns:

```
library(dplyr)

drop_columns <- c('cyl','disp','hp')
mtcars %>% 
  select(-one_of(drop_columns)) %>% 
  head(2)

              mpg drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Negating specific column names, the following drops the column "hp" and the columns from "qsec" through "gear":

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(-hp, -(qsec:gear)) %>% 
  head(2)

              mpg cyl disp drat    wt carb
Mazda RX4      21   6  160  3.9 2.620    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160  3.9 2.875    4
```

You could also negate  `contains()`, `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`, or `matches()`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(-contains('t')) %>%
  select(-starts_with('a')) %>% 
  select(-ends_with('b')) %>% 
  select(-matches('^m.+g$')) %>% 
  head(2)

              cyl disp  hp  qsec vs gear
Mazda RX4       6  160 110 16.46  0    4
Mazda RX4 Wag   6  160 110 17.02  0    4
```

Comment: Not sure this is clearer/superior than others, but I appreciate updating with new[ish] tools when they come out! Thanks for adding this to keep things fresh.

Answer (score 5):

Old thread, but here's another solution:

```
df.2 <- subset(df, select=-c(name1, name2, name3))
```

This was posted in another similar thread (though I can't find it right now). Should be sustainable code in the situation you describe, and is probably easier to read and edit than some of the other options.

Comment: The data.frame approach is otherwise the same as with data.table such that `subset(myData,,!names(myData) %in% removeCols)` where one comma difference, irritatingly similar. But this approach with `select=-c(..)` does not work, ideas why?

Comment: Hmm, no idea! I don't use data.table's

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom function to do this if you're using it for your own use to manipulate data.  I may do something like this:

```
rm.col <- function(df, ...) {
    x <- substitute(...())
    z <- Trim(unlist(lapply(x, function(y) as.character(y))))
    df[, !names(df) %in% z]
}

rm.col(mtcars, hp, mpg)
```

The first argument is the dataframe name.  the following `...` are the names of any columns you wish to remove.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that comes to my mind:

> filtered_df<-df[, setdiff(names(df),c("name1","name2") ]

essentially you are computing the set difference between full list of column names and the subset you want to filter out (name1 and name2 above).