# Subset rows in a data frame based on a vector of values

Tags: r, subset, r-faq

I have two data sets that are supposed to be the same size but aren't. I need to trim the values from A that are not in B and vice versa in order to eliminate noise from a graph that's going into a report. (Don't worry, this data isn't being permanently deleted!)

I have read the following:

- [Selecting columns in R data frame based on those *not* in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208090/selecting-columns-in-r-data-frame-based-on-those-not-in-a-vector)
- http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/subset_R.htm
- [How to combine multiple conditions to subset a data-frame using "OR"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or)

But I'm still not able to get this to work right. Here's my code:

```
bg2011missingFromBeg <- setdiff(x=eg2011$ID, y=bg2011$ID)
#attempt 1
eg2011cleaned <- subset(eg2011, ID != bg2011missingFromBeg)
#attempt 2
eg2011cleaned <- eg2011[!eg2011$ID %in% bg2011missingFromBeg]
```

The first try just eliminates the first value in the resulting setdiff vector. The second try yields and unwieldy error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(eg2012, !eg2012$ID %in% bg2012missingFromBeg) 
:  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: I don't think `merge` is appropriate here. I do not want the datasets to be combined.

Comment: No, I think `merge` is exactly appropriate. An inner join would give you only rows that are in both A and B. You can then subset the columns of the result if the merge added any extraneous ones.

Comment: This gets me the appropriate number of rows but, again, I'm left with only one data set. Moreover, from a certain perspective this data set is dirtier than the one I started with - I have one set with some rows from "End" and some rows from "Beg" and I don't know which are which.

Comment: Your first concern is mistaken. Calling merge does nothing to the two original data frames. Hence, you could do something like `A <- merge(A,B)`. And getting the correct columns is no harder than something like `merge(A,B)[,colnames(A)]` assuming none are duplicated. But if you really only are matching on one column, then adibender's solution is probably simpler for your purposes.

Comment: My concern with `merge` is that, yes, it will give me only the rows that are in both, but the data may or may not be blended. For rows in A and B, can I be certain that when both have the same index, the row will always come from A and not B? And then how do I go backwards? The data in the two data.frames is from different time periods and I do not want rows from one time period mixed with another.

Comment: Look, I agree that in your case, with only one index column, merge isn't the simplest option. But if you spend any time using it, you'll see that it is quite possible to use for this purpose. Duplicate columns have `.x` or .y` appended to their names so you can tell which of the original data frames they came from. It would require 1-2 extra lines of code, but using `merge` would work just fine.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This will give you what you want:

```
eg2011cleaned <- eg2011[!eg2011$ID %in% bg2011missingFromBeg, ]
```

The error in your second attempt is because you forgot the `,`

In general, for convenience, the specification `object[index]` subsets columns for a 2d `object`. If you want to subset rows and keep all columns you have to use the specification
`object[index_rows, index_columns]`, while `index_cols` can be left blank, which will use all columns by default.

However, you still need to include the `,` to indicate that you want to get a subset of rows instead of a subset of columns.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. I'll wait for other answers, though, just in case someone comes up with something really clever. :)

Comment: `subset` will work if you change the logical statement to `subset(eg2011, !ID %in% bg2011missingFromBeg)`

Comment: This is really the same answer as the one I wrote up.  Choose adibender's answer, since it directly solves your problem.  I only added mine for others to be able to use as a more robust reference if they stumble upon this page later.

Comment: This is also true for a faster 'data.table'

Answer (score 17):

If you really just want to subset each data frame by an index that exists in both data frames, you can do this with the 'match' function, like so:

```
data_A[match(data_B$index, data_A$index, nomatch=0),]
data_B[match(data_A$index, data_B$index, nomatch=0),]
```

This is, though, the same as:

```
data_A[data_A$index %in% data_B$index,]
data_B[data_B$index %in% data_A$index,]
```

Here is a demo:

```
# Set seed for reproducibility.
set.seed(1)

# Create two sample data sets.
data_A <- data.frame(index=sample(1:200, 90, rep=FALSE), value=runif(90))
data_B <- data.frame(index=sample(1:200, 120, rep=FALSE), value=runif(120))

# Subset data of each data frame by the index in the other.
t_A <- data_A[match(data_B$index, data_A$index, nomatch=0),]
t_B <- data_B[match(data_A$index, data_B$index, nomatch=0),]

# Make sure they match.
data.frame(t_A[order(t_A$index),], t_B[order(t_B$index),])[1:20,]

#    index     value index.1    value.1
# 27     3 0.7155661       3 0.65887761
# 10    12 0.6049333      12 0.14362694
# 88    14 0.7410786      14 0.42021589
# 56    15 0.4525708      15 0.78101754
# 38    18 0.2075451      18 0.70277874
# 24    23 0.4314737      23 0.78218212
# 34    32 0.1734423      32 0.85508236
# 22    38 0.7317925      38 0.56426384
# 84    39 0.3913593      39 0.09485786
# 5     40 0.7789147      40 0.31248966
# 74    43 0.7799849      43 0.10910096
# 71    45 0.2847905      45 0.26787813
# 57    46 0.1751268      46 0.17719454
# 25    48 0.1482116      48 0.99607737
# 81    53 0.6304141      53 0.26721208
# 60    58 0.8645449      58 0.96920881
# 30    59 0.6401010      59 0.67371223
# 75    61 0.8806190      61 0.69882454
# 63    64 0.3287773      64 0.36918946
# 19    70 0.9240745      70 0.11350771
```

Comment: Let me see if I can repeat `data_A[data_A$index %in% data_B$index,]` in words. Give me all of the rows in data_A that are in both data_A and data_B, based on their index. Do I have it right?

Comment: @Zelbinian Specifically, it says: Give me all the rows in data_A where the index value of the rows in data_A can be found in the index values in data_B.  It's a slightly different statement, but you have it basically correct.  The only difference is that we are specifically wanting the row numbers from data_A.  If you reversed the statement, it wouldn't work right.

Comment: Nice reproducible example + explanations.

Answer (score 6):

Really **human comprehensible** example (as this is the first time I am using %in%), how to compare two data frames and keep only rows containing the equal values in specific column:

```
# Set seed for reproducibility.
set.seed(1)

# Create two sample data frames.
data_A <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), value=c(1,2,3))
data_B <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), value=c(5,6,7,8))

# compare data frames by specific columns and keep only 
# the rows with equal values 
data_A[data_A$id %in% data_B$id,]   # will keep data in data_A
data_B[data_B$id %in% data_A$id,]   # will keep data in data_b
```

Results:

```
> data_A[data_A$id %in% data_B$id,]
  id value
1  1     1
2  2     2
3  3     3

> data_B[data_B$id %in% data_A$id,]
  id value
1  1     5
2  2     6
3  3     7
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments to the original post, merges / joins are well-suited for this problem.  In particular, an *inner join* will return only values that are present in both dataframes, making the`setdiff` statement unnecessary.

Using the data from Dinre's example:

**In base R:**

```
cleanedA <- merge(data_A, data_B[, "index"], by = 1, sort = FALSE)
cleanedB <- merge(data_B, data_A[, "index"], by = 1, sort = FALSE)
```

**Using the dplyr package:**

```
library(dplyr)
cleanedA <- inner_join(data_A, data_B %>% select(index))
cleanedB <- inner_join(data_B, data_A %>% select(index))
```

To keep the data as two separate tables, each containing only its own variables, this subsets the unwanted table to only its index variable before joining.  Then no new variables are added to the resulting table.