# Subsetting a dataframe using a vector

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe `My_Data`, which contains a few thousand names. I am trying to subset the data frame using a vector of names `Names.rm` but I keep getting a dataframe returned with 0 rows (despite the names being present in My_Data).

These are what I have tried:

`My_Data[My_Data$Author_name %in% Names.rm, ]`

`subset(My_Data, Author_name %in% Names.rm)`

EDIT:

Sorry I'm not sure of the proper way to format data but I'll try and give a sample:

`My_Data`:

`Author Time.period Gender
8            AERTS R Rien ECOLOGY   2001-2005      M
10      AGRAWAL AA Anurag ECOLOGY   2001-2005      M
12 AINSLIE G George NEUROSCIENCES   2001-2005      M
73        BLOB RW Richard ZOOLOGY   2001-2005      M`

`Names.rm`:

`1 AERTS R Rien ECOLOGY

2 BLOB RW Richard ZOOLOGY`

Code used: `My_Data[My_Data$Author %in% Names.rm, ]`

Expected output:
`Author     Time.period  Gender
8            AERTS R Rien ECOLOGY   2001-2005      M
73        BLOB RW Richard ZOOLOGY   2001-2005      M`

Actual output (when tried with whole dataframe):

`[1] Author      Time.period Gender

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

EDIT 2:
OK so it worked there with that subset of the data, but it isn't working when I try and do it on my whole dataset. Is there a limit to the size of the dataset you can do this for?

I have read:
[Selecting columns in R data frame based on those *not* in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208090/selecting-columns-in-r-data-frame-based-on-those-not-in-a-vector)
and
[Select rows from a data frame based on values in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612235/select-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-values-in-a-vector)

Comment: If you get 0 rows, the names are not present in `My_Data`. Also, if you don't post your actual data, it's difficult to give any kind of useful help

Comment: `mtcars[mtcars$cyl %in% 6,]` works for me, so your patterns do work Like nicola said, its probably a mismatch in your `Names.rm` so post an small example (not the whole thing) of your data and names to drop

Comment: It might be helpful if you could reproduce the error and supply some data / code to demonstrate where your issue is occurring.