# Not / negative column select using braces syntax

Tags: r

```
names <- names(mtcars)
str(mtcars[names[1]]) # shows the str for mpg data frame
```

I would like to select everything EXCEPT names[1] which in this example is mpg.

Tried:

```
str(mtcars[!names[1]])
Error in !names[1] : invalid argument type
```

Also tried

```
str(mtcars[-names[1]])
Error in -names[1] : invalid argument to unary operator
```

How can I select mtcars minus names[1] feature using square braces syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting columns in R data frame based on those \*not\* in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208090/selecting-columns-in-r-data-frame-based-on-those-not-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str(mtcars[!names %in% names[1]])

'data.frame':   32 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use numerical indexing for selection, you can just use a - in front of that to do the reverse.

```
str(mtcars[names[1]]) # shows the str for mpg data frame
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...

str(mtcars[names[-1]])
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```